# regex remove all periods that are not following by digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I have `str.replace(/.(?![0-9])/g, '')`.
But it removes everything except the period and the digit after the period.
For example "3.14" becomes ".1"

What I want is:

```
"3.14" -> "3.14"
"hello.world" -> "helloworld"
".hi." -> "hi"
"hi.25" -> "hi.25"
```

What is the regex for doing this?

Comment: Escape the dot, `/\.(?!\d)/g`.

Answer (score 3):

`.` is a metacharacter (matches any character except line breaks by default) in regular expressions. You need to escape it:

```
str.replace(/\.(?![0-9])/g, '')
```

or

```
str.replace(/[.](?![0-9])/g, '')
```

depending on your preference.

Note that you can replace `[0-9]` by `\d`.

Comment: you're welcome. please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer. that will give me some credit and more importantly, show future visitors that and how your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't escape the dot it means "match any character."

```
str.replace(/\.(?![0-9])/g, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are correct, I'll point out another option (which doesn't use a look-ahead):

```
str.replace(/\.+([^0-9]|$)/g, '$1')
```

The `$1` is special syntax to return the thing which matched the first set of brackets.

---

Turns out that this method is *slower* than lookahead (http://jsperf.com/regexp-look-ahead-speed), but I still think it's interesting as another option. I personally find capturing tokens like this to be more intuitive and flexible. But if you need speed, go with the others.

Comment: Are you sure that a lookahead has a larger impact on performance than capturing (which is also pretty expensive)? I think you should provide at least a simple benchmark with that claim. Also the end-of-string thing would be fixed by using `([^0-9]|$)`, which you might want to add.

Comment: 100,000 repetitions of your and my pattern on `.hi.25.foo.` gives ~155ms for your approach and ~140ms for mine. I appreciate you showing a different possible solution, but (at least for the current case) the claim that capturing is faster than a lookahead is simply wrong.

Comment: I fixed some more omissions, and seems you're right: http://jsperf.com/regexp-look-ahead-speed I'll update the answer

Comment: @m.buettner I already fixed that; notice the `+` in the updated answer (and that was included in the benchmark I ran too).

Comment: I just noticed that upon opening the benchmark again. nevermind then.